# Error when loading Android APK via ADB - StorageManager.getVolumes()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb, android-source, android-debug

I am getting the error below when i attempt to load a custom APK on to Android.  It's an empty test service.

Thanks,

-Eric

```
adb: failed to install test.apk:

Exception occurred while executing:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List android.os.storage.StorageManager.getVolumes()' on a null object reference

        at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:186)

        at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:150)

        at com.android.internal.content.PackageHelper.resolveInstallVolume(PackageHelper.java:165)

        at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstaller
```